# puppeteer get img from html with alt attribute

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

`<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 nopadding text-center"><!-- Start Product Photo --><div class="row"><img src="/products/ca/downloads/images/54631.jpg" alt="Product image 1"><br><img src="/products/ca/downloads/images/54631_WIP.jpg" alt="Product image 2"><br><p>images not to scale</p></div><!-- End Product Photo --></div>`

I have the following html.

Via puppeteer, how can I get the image source for Product image 2 (the source from alt = value)

```
    product =  await page.evaluate(() => {
   let image = document.querySelector ("").src

    });
```

in the let image, how can I use the dom selectors to latch on to the img src of alt value = Product image 2?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use an [Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). I believe the exact selector you're looking for is `img[alt="Product image 2"]`

```js
let image = document.querySelector('img[alt="Product image 2"]').src;
console.log(image);
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 nopadding text-center">
  <!-- Start Product Photo -->
  <div class="row"><img src="/products/ca/downloads/images/54631.jpg" alt="Product image 1"><br><img src="/products/ca/downloads/images/54631_WIP.jpg" alt="Product image 2"><br>
    <p>images not to scale</p>
  </div>
  <!-- End Product Photo -->
</div>
```

Comment: What if I wanted to grab all  image src class from col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 nopadding text-center ?

Comment: @Tekky There may be a better / more accurate selector but I don't know the entire dom structure you're working with. This will get you what you're looking for though 
`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div[class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 nopadding text-center"] img')).map(img => img.src)` [codepen](https://codepen.io/adamlacombe/pen/dyGeevx?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`img[alt=desired value]` in the query selector
And then with the `image` variable you can extract the `src` variable with `image.src`